# Efeito com hover em dois elementos

Tags: css, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, css-hover

Estou tentando fazer um efeito que, ao passar o mouse em algum tópico, os outros diminuem a opacidade, destacando o tópico no qual o mouse está.
Além disso, o hover troca a cor de um cinza para um verde.
Está quase tudo funcionando.
Aqui eu coloquei a parte principal do efeito (por isso está desconfigurado), mas o efeito está sendo feito corretamente.
Se eu passar o mouse em cima do ícone, ok, o ícone e a frase ficam verdes.
Mas se eu passar o mouse em cima da frase, somente ela fica verde.

```css
/****** Auxiliar ******/ 
.col-xs-5ths,
.col-sm-5ths,
.col-md-5ths,
.col-lg-5ths {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-xs-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}    
    
/****** Auxiliar ******/    
    
    .icones_servicos{
   padding-top: 60px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .icones_servicos a {
   transition: all 0.4s linear;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #00E394;
  }

  .icones_servicos h4, .icones_servicos a p,  .icones_servicos i{
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
  }

  .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) a, .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) h4, .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) a p { 
   opacity: 0.5;
  } 

   .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) i{
   opacity: 0.5;
   } 
 
  .icones_servicos i{
   color: #8A919B;
   /* background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00E394, #007c78, #006c77, #005c71, #004c66);   
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; */
   font-size: 44px;
  }
  
  .icones_servicos h4{
   color: #8A919B;
   font-size: 1.02rem;
  }

  .icones_servicos i:hover, .icones_servicos i:hover ~ .categoria-servico{
   color: #00E394;
  }

 .icones_servicos h4:hover, .icones_servicos h4:hover ~ .icones-home{
  color: #00E394;
 }
  
  .icon_wrapclearfix{
   border-top: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
   margin-top: 4em;
  }
  
  .icon_wrapclearfix a {
   -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
   -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
   transition-duration: .5s;
   padding-top: 5em;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .icon_wrapclearfix a:before {
   border-radius: 1em;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: -0.05em;
   height: 1em;
   width: 1em;
   background-color: #00E394;
   content: "";
   margin-left: 1em;
  } 

  .icon_wrapclearfix a:hover:before{
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
   transition: all .15s ease-out;  
  }

  .icon_wrapclearfix_outros a:before {
   margin-left: 8.7em;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<section id="about" class="padding bg_light">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="text-center">
    <h2 class="heading"><span>Nossos </span> Serviços <span class="divider-center"></span><div class="diviver_aux_30"></div></h2>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
     <h2 class="heading"></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="icon_wrapclearfix">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
       <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
        <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Contabilidade</h4>

       </a>
      </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
       <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
        <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Escrituração Fiscal</h4>

       </a>
      </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
       <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
        <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Rotinas Trabalhistas (DP)</h4>
 
       </a>
      </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
       <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
        <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Tributos</h4>

       </a>
      </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
       <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
        <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Finanças</h4>
       </a>
      </div>
         </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o `hover` no `<a>` e troque a color de tudo que está dentro `> * {}`

Essa regra vai resolver seu problema

```
.icones_servicos a:hover > * {
    color: #00E394 !important;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja funcionando

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    /****** Auxiliar ******/
    .col-xs-5ths,
    .col-sm-5ths,
    .col-md-5ths,
    .col-lg-5ths {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .col-xs-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .col-sm-5ths {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        .col-md-5ths {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .col-lg-5ths {
            width: 20%;
            float: left;
        }
    }

    /****** Auxiliar ******/

    .icones_servicos {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .icones_servicos a {
        transition: all 0.4s linear;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #00E394;
    }

    .icones_servicos h4,
    .icones_servicos a p,
    .icones_servicos i {
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
    }

    .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) a,
    .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) h4,
    .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) a p {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .row:hover .icones_servicos:not(:hover) i {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .icones_servicos i {
        color: #8A919B;
        /* background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00E394, #007c78, #006c77, #005c71, #004c66);   
                    -webkit-background-clip: text;
                    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; */
        font-size: 44px;
    }

    .icones_servicos h4 {
        color: #8A919B;
        font-size: 1.02rem;
    }

    .icones_servicos i:hover,
    .icones_servicos i:hover ~ .categoria-servico {
        color: #00E394;
    }

    .icones_servicos h4:hover,
    .icones_servicos h4:hover ~ .icones-home {
        color: #00E394;
    }

    .icon_wrapclearfix {
        border-top: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
        margin-top: 4em;
    }

    .icon_wrapclearfix a {
        -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
        -moz-transition-duration: .5s;
        transition-duration: .5s;
        padding-top: 5em;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .icon_wrapclearfix a:before {
        border-radius: 1em;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: -0.05em;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        background-color: #00E394;
        content: "";
        margin-left: 1em;
    }

    .icon_wrapclearfix a:hover:before {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all .15s ease-out;
        transition: all .15s ease-out;
    }

    .icon_wrapclearfix_outros a:before {
        margin-left: 8.7em;
    }

    .icones_servicos a:hover > * {
        color: #00E394 !important;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <section id="about" class="padding bg_light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2 class="heading"><span>Nossos </span> Serviços <span class="divider-center"></span>
                    <div class="diviver_aux_30"></div>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="heading"></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="icon_wrapclearfix">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
                            <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Contabilidade</h4>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
                            <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Escrituração Fiscal</h4>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
                            <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Rotinas Trabalhistas (DP)</h4>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
                            <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Tributos</h4>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5ths col-md-5ths text-center icones_servicos" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-address-book icones-home"></i>
                            <h4 class="text-capitalize bottom20 margin10 categoria-servico">Finanças</h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```